# how to close or hide my alert boite dialog before a laps of time?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

in my application I upload some items and data from internet, so I would show AlertDialog.Builder when when this uplaods was not finish.

that will be automatically.

I have no idea how to do it, put callbacks or some what, do synchronization,... ?

thinks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AsyncTask! An example below

```
private class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{


     @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {

       // Show your dialog here

  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // do your upload here
    return null;
  }


  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

      // dismiss your dialog here 
  }
}
```

Call you AsyncTask as follows

```
new ShowDialogAsyncTask().execute();
```

Comment: thimks so much!! 
I do not know why I forgot this easy solution.
I'm sorry it was a very bad question !